# How to force new instance of SQLAlchemy class

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, instantiation

I am trying to create a new instance of a class within a function. The instance is created new the first time through, although when I try to create an additional instance (by revisiting the route), I am getting back a reference to the original object.

This is coming from the way I have built out the app. See simplified code below:

```
@tests.route('/generate_test/<t_type>', methods=['GET'])
def generate_test(t_type):
    test_obj = t[t_type]['obj']
    ...
    return test_obj
```

Where t is a dictionary like below:

```
t = {
     'footests':  {'obj': FooTest(),
                   'name': 'Foo Test',
                   ...
                  },
     ...
}
```

Since there are many different types of tests, I was hoping I could use this method to provide all the extra details that are associated with a certain kind of test. When I first generate a new test, the test object `FooTest` is new, meaning `id = None` etc.

Although, once I come through a second time and attempt to generate a new test, the instance in the dictionary `t` is still associated with the test instance from the first time, meaning `id = <id_from_last_time>`

I tried to expunge the object using `db_session.expunge(test_obj)` and `del(test_obj)` (both within my `Flask` route), although I am still getting a reference to the original object.

I want the dictionary `t` to provide a **new object instance** each time I call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need to create the instance every time your route is called, instead of simply reading the value of a previously created instance.

In your route:

```
test_obj = t[t_type]['obj']()
```

In your `t` definition:

```
t = {
     'footests':  {'obj': FooTest,
                   'name': 'Foo Test',
                   ...
                  },
     ...
}
```